# Loop cannot reach the limit

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-optimization

I want to understand why this `for` doesn't stop its execution to 10. See the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float i;
  for (i = 0.0; i <= 10; i += 0.01)
    printf("Iteration %g\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

The latest iterations are:

> Iteration 9.96013
>   Iteration 9.97013
>   Iteration 9.98013
>   Iteration 9.99013

Why this behaviour ?

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe could be used to flag as duplicate.

Comment: You accumulate rounding errors because you add a small number which is not exactly representable as a IEEE floating point number (0.01) many times to another float. Additionally you make an exact comparison which is almost always wrong with floating points. The detailed rules how to compute with and compare floating point numbers are difficult (and I don't know them). You can avoid accumulating rounding errors by obtaining the steps through multiplication: `for(int=0; i<101; i++) { printf("Iteration %lg\n", i*0.01);`. Comparisons usually involve FLT_EPSILON from `float.h`.

Comment: As a comparison, you could try to add (1.0/128) 128 times...

Comment: Another thing: Don't call floats `i`. Just don't ;-).

Comment: Thinking in decimal: what happens if you add one third (0.333333~) 3 times? You don't get `1.0`. One hundredth is exactly representable in decimal (by definition) but one third is not.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I find it in an example. I never do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the last iteration, you see `Iteration 9.99013` because if the loop iterated again, `i` would equal 10.00013, which is greater than 10, your looping condition. The `for` loop only continues as long as the condition is satisfied.

As @WeatherVane pointed out, you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), which explains why you see the additional 0.00013 at the end of your `i` variable.

Comment: I think OP is asking why sum 0.01 to 0 many times gives X.XXX13 at the end of iterations.

Comment: I don't think that necessarily warranted the downvote, but I edited.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. Well done, about the edit.

Answer (score 0):

> 10.00013 <= 10 condition false so control goes out of for loop